# Get hidden columns of smart table in Dropdownlist AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, smart-table

I am new to AngularJS, can anyone help in achieving this.
I have a smart table with 4 columns, initially I am setting `col 3` and `col 4` to `ng-show=false`, so when I load the page only `col 1` and `col 2` are getting displayed. It's well and good till here.

**my question:**
Can I have `col3` and `col4` in a dropdown so that the user can click and make those columns visible.

Visible columns should be not available in the dropdown, suppose if `col1`,`col2`,`col3`are visible, then only `col4` is to be shown in dropdown.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", ['smart-table']);

myApp.controller('customCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var rowCollection = [
        { col1: "a", col2: "b", col3: "c", col4: "d" },
        { col1: "a1", col2: "b1", col3: "c1", col4: "d1" },
        { col1: "a2", col2: "b2", col3: "c2", col4: "d2" },
        { col1: "a3", col2: "b3", col3: "c3", col4: "d3" },
        { col1: "a4", col2: "b4", col3: "c4", col4: "d4" },
        { col1: "a5", col2: "b5", col3: "c5", col4: "d5" },

    ];


    $scope.rowCollection = rowCollection;


});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.tablerow:hover {
    background-color: #25CCDA;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #999999;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/smart-table.debug.js"></script>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="customCtrl">
    <select>
        <option value="add column">add column</option>
        
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table st-table="rowCollection">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col1</th>
                <th>col2</th>
                <th ng-show="col3">col3</th>
                <th ng-show="col4">col4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                <td>{{ row.col1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.col2 }}</td>
                <td ng-show="col3">{{ row.col3 }}</td>
                <td ng-show="col4">{{ row.col4 }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you provide a plnkr/jsfiddle to show what have you tried?

Comment: Create a columns object or array and use that for setting `ng-show` and filter it for `ng-options`

Comment: Could any plesae create plnkr/fiddle for this, it would be really helpfull

Comment: @Hussain I'm not getting your question, properly; lets say if col1, col2 is visible it wont be shown in the dropdown which means col3, col4 will be shown in dropdown. If user selects col3 or col4 from dropdown what do you expect will be the output

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
When user selects col3 or col4, those respective column should be visible and removed from dropdown.
which means that dropdown contains only hidden columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following work around

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myApp.controller('customCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.enableColumns = function(header) {
    header.visible = !header.visible;
  };
  $scope.colHeaders = [{
    name: "col1",
    visible: true
  }, {
    name: "col2",
    visible: true
  }, {
    name: "col3",
    visible: false
  }, {
    name: "col4",
    visible: false
  }]
  var rowCollection = [{
      col1: "a",
      col2: "b",
      col3: "c",
      col4: "d"
    }, {
      col1: "a1",
      col2: "b1",
      col3: "c1",
      col4: "d1"
    }, {
      col1: "a2",
      col2: "b2",
      col3: "c2",
      col4: "d2"
    }, {
      col1: "a3",
      col2: "b3",
      col3: "c3",
      col4: "d3"
    }, {
      col1: "a4",
      col2: "b4",
      col3: "c4",
      col4: "d4"
    }, {
      col1: "a5",
      col2: "b5",
      col3: "c5",
      col4: "d5"
    }

  ];


  $scope.rowCollection = rowCollection;


});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tablerow:hover {
  background-color: #25CCDA;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #999999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">

<head>
</head>

<body ng-controller="customCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="enableColumns(selectedItem)" ng-options="header.name for header in colHeaders|filter:{visible: false}">
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in colHeaders" ng-show="header.visible">{{header.name}}<div><a href="javacript:void(0);" ng-click="enableColumns(header)" >hide</a></div></th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
        <td ng-repeat="header in colHeaders" ng-show="header.visible">{{ row[header.name] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```